# Read first line from latest file

Tags: shell

I’m working on requirement where I need to read first line from latest file under a directory. In a directory  I can have multiple files but I want to read first line of latest file out all files which are having PPP in their file name.

I know how to read first line of file and write into a file

```
head -n 1 jsonPPPvp.txt > output.txt
```

But how can I pick latest file ( as per the time stamp) out of all files in a directory which are having PPP in it..?

Any suggestions please...!

I’ve written a command

Answer (score 1):

It is not maybe the best solution but it works (by latest file, I have considered the file modified with the most recent timestamp ):

```
ls -ltra
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 3 allanrobert primarygroup 4096 Feb 15 17:37 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 allanrobert primarygroup 4096 Feb 15 17:37 .
-rw-r--r-- 1 allanrobert primarygroup    6 Feb 15 17:40 file2PPP2
-rw-r--r-- 1 allanrobert primarygroup    6 Feb 15 17:40 other
-rw-r--r-- 1 allanrobert primarygroup    6 Feb 15 17:40 file3PPP3
-rw-r--r-- 1 allanrobert primarygroup    6 Feb 15 17:40 other2
-rw-r--r-- 1 allanrobert primarygroup    6 Feb 15 17:40 other1
-rw-r--r-- 1 allanrobert primarygroup    6 Feb 15 17:40 file1PPP
```

file content:

```
cat file1PPP 
a
b
c
```

Command:

```
find .  -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '*PPP*' -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs head -1
a
```

Beware of spaces in filenames!

Comment: What happens if there is a `PPPold/` directory? (add the `-type f` option to `find`) and don't you need the `-maxdepth 1` option to prevent a recursive find?

Answer (score 1):

**Using `find` with `-print0` and `xargs -0` in a command substitution**

Your optimal solution, though still requiring 4 subshells, will protect against all caveats in filenames by having `find` output *nul-terminated* filenames that can be used in conjunction with `xargs -0` to form a nul-terminated list of filenames to be passed to `ls` for sorting in reverse selecting the last file with `tail -n1` and the first line in that file with `head -n1`.

Using the `-maxdepth 1` option to find limits the search to the current directory and prevent recursing into subdirectories (remove it if you want to search the entire directory tree below the current directory), e.g.

```
head -n1 $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*PPP*" -print0 | 
           xargs -0 ls -rt | 
           tail -n 1)
```

In addition to working with nul-terminated filenames, it will benefit from letting `xargs` form the list to sort rather than looping to find the newest.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = `ls -Art | head -n 1 `
head -1 $temp
```

Comment: What happens if there happen to be subdirectories present?

Comment: if there is sub directories instead of ls we can use `find -type f -name * | sort |head -n 1`

Answer (score 0):

`head -n 1 $(find ./ -name "*PPP*" -type f | xargs  ls -rt1 | tail -n 1)`

The drawback of the command above is that you must have a `*PPP*` file in your directory, otherwise the command produces wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
ls -tr | grep "PPP" | tail -n 1 | xargs head -n 1
```